# Can a SOCKS client listen for connections from a remote client

Tags: socks

I have a situation where a PC (PC-1) is behind a firewall and is running a webserver listening for connections. PC-1 can connect to a SOCKS server (S-1). I have another PC (PC-2) that wants to connect to webserver on PC-1 through S-1.

Is that something SOCKS is designed for?

If so, can you guide me in what I need to do to set it up?

All systems are running Linux.

Answer (score 5):

PC-2 would need access to S-1 in order to initiate a SOCKS connection through S-1 to PC-1.

The SOCKS protocol does support a client binding to ports, but only for the purposes of using a multi-connection protocol (such as FTP). PC-1 can't bind a port that will listen to the world.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Do you know of something that could do this?  I have looked into netcat, but the HTTP protocol does not play well with it.

Comment: Just do an iptables port forward on S-1. If you can't, what are you doing here? It's also possible to do it with SSH port forwarding, but not if the admin of S-1 has turned off that feature. You haven't described our problem nearly enough for us to help you further.